# DolphinDB - high memory usage after scheduled jobs are executed

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, memcached, dolphindb

I check the performance monitoring metrics on DolphinDB’s web interface after scheduled jobs are finished, but it shows that the node still uses a lot of memory:

[image]

I executed `pnodeRun(objs)` and `pnodeRun(objs{true})` to release all variables in the cluster. Both returned empty, meaning there is no variable taking up memory. I also used `pnodeRun(clearAllCache)` to clear cached data, but the memory usage stayed unchanged. Is there another way to troubleshoot such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory usage of a node is close to *[maxMemSize](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/DatabaseandDistributedComputing/Configuration/StandaloneMode.html)*, release all cached data on the node via `clearAllCache()`. If memory usage is still very high, check the following items:

- Check if there are sessions consuming too much memory via
  `getSessionMemoryStat()` and identify the corresponding users. Execute
  `objs(true)` to identify the variables (including the variables shared
  by other sessions) occupying large amount of memory in the current
  session.
- Check if there are background jobs or interactive jobs running longer
  than expected via `getRecentJobs()` and `getConsoleJobs()`. The memory
  usage of these jobs is not reflected in the result of
  `getSessionMemoryStat()`.
- Check if the streaming data is consuming too much memory via
  `getStreamingStat()`.

See [DolphinDB Memory Management](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/memory_management.md) for more information.